# How to configure URL paths using the pathauto module for multilingual sites?

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I am working on multilingual drupal website.To generate content path(i.e url) I am using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. I have not configured this module.

When I add content from basic page it sets **content/[node:title]** as url path seetings. It is fine for english language. But for other language content I want to set url same as english content.

What path pattern I have to set so that url path for nepali content is same as english content ?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Pathauto i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_i18n) module for this. Excerpt from its project page:

> ... by default Pathauto creates alias only for one language or for all languages one alias. This module provides functionality to create aliases for each language. Also this module will be helpful, if you use field translation and you want show node on all language with paths, different from node/nid.

This module contains 3 submodules which can be used to enable separate functionality for each entity:

- pathauto_i18n_node (for nodes).
- pathauto_i18n_user (for users).
- pathauto_i18n_taxonomy (for taxonomy).

## Example (also from project page):

When you create node without pathauto_i18n:

- English alias: en/articles/first_article
- Italiano alias: not exist
- Deutsche alias: not exist

When you create node with pathauto_i18n:

- English alias: en/articles/first_article
- Italiano alias: it/articolo/first_article
- Deutsche alias: de/artikel/first_article

Comment: Just curious if my answer was of any help ... Hope it's OK to ask since there is no feedback via any other comments or so. Also because looking at your profile, it shows that you haven't visited the "Tour" yet (link within help, upper right). Which is also why you're probably not aware of what's mentioned in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ...